# HTC One X switches to silent on its own?

Tags: settings, htc-one-x

My HTC One X constantly is switching from vibrate to silent on its own. I put it on vibrate, put it down, and next time I look at my phone, it is on silent. This is extremely annoying because I am missing phone calls and texts because my phone is on silent, when I put it on vibrate.

Anybody else have this problem or know how to fix it?

Comment: Sounds like a gesture related thing, put the phone down, it switches to silent... Is there something in the HTC Sense itself, in a setting somewhere for **Gesture** related...?

Comment: Are you sure you are not accidentally hitting the volume-down button? This changes vibration to silent as well. Otherwise, I know my HTC One S can detect when it's in a bag or pocket and will increase ring volume, or you can flip it over during calls to activate speaker etc... Try what t0mm13b said.

Comment: t0mm13b: what do you mean? in the gestures the only option is "enable 3-finger output gestures and ignore gestures with more finger" and i dont have that selected.

Mario: i am certain it isn't on accident. I turn it to vibrate then turn off the screen and then next time i turn the screen on it is on silent. you can't change the volume when the screen is off.

Comment: Motorola has those SmartActions that do certain things at certain times of the day. Does HTC have something like that?